# More efficent way to loop through list then using a double loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a dataset in the format of a list of dicts that I would like to loop through and extract a subset of that dataset based on a match to a value in another list of values.

I am currently doing this in the way of two seperate `for x in y` loops, as shown below under *sample code*, but I'm sure that this is very inefficient and it's taking an extremely long time with large lists to look through.

***example data in CSV format:***

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║     City     ║    State     ║ 2013 Estimate ║ 2013 Land Area ║ 2013 Popular Density ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ New York     ║ New York     ║ 8405837       ║ 302.6 sq mi    ║ 27012 per sq mi      ║
║ Los Angeles  ║ California   ║ 3884307       ║ 468.7 sq mi    ║ 8092 per sq mi       ║
║ Chicago      ║ Illinois     ║ 2718782       ║ 227.6 sq mi    ║ 11842 per sq mi      ║
║ Houston      ║ Texas        ║ 2195914       ║ 599.6 sq mi    ║ 3501 per sq mi       ║
║ Philadelphia ║ Pennsylvania ║ 1,553,165     ║ 134.1 sq mi    ║ 11379 per sq mi      ║
║ Phoenix      ║ Arizona      ║ 1513367       ║ 516.7 sq mi    ║ 2798 per sq mi       ║
║ San Antonio  ║ Texas        ║ 1409019       ║ 460.9 sq mi    ║ 2880 per sq mi       ║
║ San Diego    ║ California   ║ 1355896       ║ 325.2 sq mi    ║ 4020 per sq mi       ║
║ Dallas       ║ Texas        ║ 1257676       ║ 340.5 sq mi    ║ 3518 per sq mi       ║
║ San Jose     ║ California   ║ 998537        ║ 176.5 sq mi    ║ 5359 per sq mi       ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

***sample code***

```
#read data into list of dicts
import csv 
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    data = list(csv.DictReader(csv_file))

# cities of interest to extract from larger data
int_cities = [['New York'],['Houston'],['Pheonix'],['San Jose']]

# loop through data and look for match in data['City'] and interest_cities, append match to int_cities_data
int_cities_data = []
for i in data:
    for u in int_cities:
        if i['City'] == u:
            int_cities_data.append(i)
```

As I state, this currently works, but it takes a very long time when I have to loop through ~2M rows in `data` and look if there is a match across another 50k rows in `int_cities`.

How can I make this more efficient?

### ***EDIT 2014-08-22 9:30 PM EST***

I forgot that the data is too large to use `csv.DictReader` so I have been using the following to read my data into a list of dicts (after removing the header):

*This is untested*

```
header = ['City','State','2013 Estimate','2013 Land Area','2013 Popular Density']
data = [{key: value for (key, value) in zip(header, line.strip().split(','))} for line in open('data.csv') if line['City'] in int_cities]
```

I tried to modify the above code I've used to load my data into a list of dicts without using `csv.DictReader`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of reading all the data in the file into a list, then iterating over that list to search for the cities you want, iterate over the csv file one line at a time, and only add items to the list if they're for the cities you care about. That way you don't need to store the entire file in memory, and you don't need to iterate over it twice (once to build the complete list, then again to pull the entries you care about out of it).

Additionally, store the cities you care about in a `set` instead of a `list`, so you can do lookups in `O(1)` time, instead of `O(n)`. This will likely drastically improve performance if you're doing lots of lookups (and it sounds like you are).

```
#read data into list of dicts
import csv 

int_cities = set(['New York', 'Houston', 'Phoenix', 'San Jose'])
int_cities_data = []
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    for line in csv.DictReader(csv_file):
        if line['City'] in int_cities:
            int_cities_data.append(line)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    int_cities_data = [line for line in csv.DictReader(csv_file) if line['City'] in int_cities]
```

Comment: `line['City']`  won't be in `int_cities`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried this with his test data and it seemed to work ok. What do you mean?

Comment: If the OP's code was working, `if i['City'] == u:` is comparing `i['City']` to each if the sublists in `int_cities` not to strings

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah, yeah, I noticed that, too. But the csv data he provided doesn't parse that way - `line['City']` will just be a string, not a list. However, if it *did* parse to a list for some reason, using `if line['City'][0] in int_cities:` would work and allow `int_cities` to remain a `set`.

Comment: I tried running my edited code that does not use `csv.DictReader` since the data is too large for it, and I am getting the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @green_bean_4_u Have you tried using my code with `csv.DictReader`? Odds are, your code was only too big with `DictReader` because you were trying to make `list` out of your entire data set. If you don't do that, `DictReader` iterates over the csv file one line at a time, so it shouldn't put much burden on memory. You would only run into trouble if the filtered `int_cities_data` list ends up being too large to fit into memory.

Comment: With my actual file, `int_cities` has 50k cities.  This data is a .csv file currently.  I've been trying to read the data into a list of strings, and then put that into a set, but haven't been successful.  I've been try the following:  `int_cities = set(csv.reader(with open('int_cities.csv', 'rb'))`

Comment: @dano yes, one city per line

Comment: @green_bean_4_u In that case you can just use `int_cities = set(line.rstrip() for line in open('int_cities.csv'))`. No need to use a `csv.reader`.

Comment: Thanks again @dano, absolutely perfect!

Comment: @dano - `Error: field larger than field limit (131702)`